# Why when I edit style.min.css on the theme editor on wp it doesn't work but in the file manager on the server it does?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was having a problem- Adding my own CSS code to WP theme and plugins wasn't working. I used the plugin Contact Form 7 for WP and I wanted to add my own CSS to it. To do so I checked on Chrome DevTools (F11 on your keyboard) for the CSS file and saw that it's called style.min.css, and indeed when I was editing it (on DevTools) I was getting results.
Then I found the file on WP theme editor, but when I made the changes there it didn't work.

So I went to the file manager on my server, found that CSS file there (WP folder > wp-content > themes > my theme name > style.min.css 
Changed it there and it did work!

Here is a piece of the code (I simply added the `text-align:right;`):
`input,select,textarea{
    display:block;width:100%;font-family:inherit;font-size:1rem;height:2.5rem;outline:0;vertical-align:middle;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #f1f1f1;border-radius:3px;box-shadow:none;padding:0 12px;
    text-align:right;
    }`
[And while I'm at it, do you know why some of the CSS file in WP have indentation and others don't?]

So my (main) question is this- why didn't it work on WP editor? Does it take some time for it to update? (I waited a while)

This question is out of curiosity since my problem was already solved

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a bad idea, you should never edit plugins and themes's files directly, otherwise all the changes will be lost once you updated them.

If you want to customize a theme then create a child-theme.

And for any style changes there is already a way to do it, just add your custom CSS here *wp-admin > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS*

[image]

Comment: That's only good for the theme, but if I'm building a landing page (using Elementor) it doesn't work.

Comment: Even with the theme it doesn't alwayes work (for example `dir:rtl;` doesn't work) and that was my question- why? And not how to do it.